# Is Java's "String" hashcode function thread-safe if its cache setter does not use locks?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is the code from Java's String hashCode function

```
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
            char val[] = value;

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                h = 31 * h + val[i];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

As you can see, it checks if the hash ("private int hash") == 0 and otherwise sets it. The constructor does not always set this value (and why else the check of course).

So although it would be quite hard to reproduce in practical usages, it looks like one could have a race condition on this hash right?

I mean, once you put it in a hashmap, for example, it would be safe, unless you first sent it off to another thread. But if the string was on two threads and simultaneously added to a hashmap, the hashMap function could take the partially written "hash" value and return it.

Comment: I think the `hash=h`  is thread-safe (there'll be 0 or the value of `h` in the variable `hash`, nothing else) , and all the others does not matter. It does not matter, 'cause if I count the hash multiple times, it'll be the same, always.

Comment: @NagyVilmos I was under the impression that you could read a partially written memory value. That would be CPU and not language dependent and I don't have a source for that. Would like to figure that out though. This =0 and no lock pattern is a good one if it is correct.

Comment: @user1122069 only for `long` and `double` a partially written value is possible.

Comment: @user1122069 as @bowmore mentioned, the JVM writes atomically all primitives, except the `long` and `double` types. I'm not sure, but on the 64 bit architectures those two is atomically written also.

Comment: The algorithm is idempotent so if a thread doesn't see the `hash` value set in another thread, it simply calculates the same value as the other thread did. It is impossible for the method to return a different value.

Comment: @NagyVilmos Thanks. So this is a feature of the JVM right and wouldn't hold true for a language like C, except maybe with 1-bit types?

Comment: in 64bit JVM even long and double are thread safe as one CPU cycle can deal but we can't obviously depends on JVM so  for consistency, use volatile keyword. http://archive.is/PuaaF#selection-8433.107-8437.73

Answer (score 11):

Theoretically one can generate code that would cause multiple simultaneous threads to read the 0 valued hash and go into the calculation part. That would be "wasteful", but safe, since the function operates on the immutable characters, and each instance would calculate the exact same hash value.

Comment: Makes sense, but do you have a source that show that there are no "partial writes" to the integer that can be done? Java integer is 32 bit, so lets say, to have written 1 bit and then read the 32 as 0s?

I remember something about CPUs blocking memory access in 32-bit sections, but if true that would assume that this integer is properly aligned on 1 32 bit block instead of spanning 2.

Comment: @user1122069: integer access in java is guaranteed to be atomic. Long is not.

Comment: Theoretically one can generate code that would cause multiple simultaneous threads to read the 0 - is it some sort of "safe" race condition?

Comment: @DmitryZagorulkin - multiple threads reading the same variable, without any writes involved is not a race condition at all. It is perfectly safe to do. When writes come into play, you need to consider barriers / locking / etc...

Comment: It is also worthwhile to mention that hashCode computes from immutable value, thus it is threadsafe to compute it

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing to `hashCode` is not properly synchronized according to the Java Memory Model but it is safe nevertheless.

If multiple threads write to `hashCode` then, due to the immutability of a `String` object, it is implicit that the calculation yields the same result. Assume that this result is `x` then any thread is guaranteed to observe either `0` or `x` because `int` is atomic on all VMs. In case that a thread observes `0`, it simply recalculates the hash code which is guaranteed to yield `x`, thus only resetting the value if another thread applied the operation concurrently or within its thread-local cache.

In this sense, the outcome is deterministic. At the same time, it is not required to synchronized threads for sharing this instance. Assume that you would have some key `"foo"` throughout your application used by all of your threads. Due to Java's string deduplication, this string constant would be shared among all of your threads which would have to synchronize only to save them the trouble to recompute the hash codes. Computing the hash code is however a very cheap operation whereas synchronization is very expensive. As the correctness is given, this optimization makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the results from the comments section - reads and writes of integer are done atomicly in the Java VM.

The assosiated spec can be found under "Atomic Access" on the Oracle website.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Java, but that does not seem to be a "race condition". I would say that it is a "lazy compute the hash, and after that, cache the value".

So, no use to compute the hash in constructor, if no one will call the hashCode method. But after the first one calls hashCode, then the value is computed, will never change, so you can cache it for further calls.

LATER EDIT:

Now I see your point. That is the purpose of the local variable. And not using a "thread safe" mechanism is a "performance decision", as creating a lock, using it, releasing it comes with a cost, while the case you are talking about (2 threads calling hashCode at the same time) is a pretty difficult to reach in real life scenario, and the result will be the same hash value.

Comment: There is a data race, but it's harmless because it will return the same hash value in all threads regardless of which thread wins the race.  The worst thing that can happen is some wasted CPU cycles if two or more threads both decide to do the computation.